# How to run cv::dnn::blobFromImages on multiple images and interpret it

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-learning, yolo

I need to run `cv::dnn::blobFromImages` on multiple images in c++, in order to detect objects, faster than one image for `cv::dnn::blobFromImage`. But as you know `blob`  is a `Mat` file, so how could I check result on second , third and ... images?

```
cv::Mat blob = cv::dnn::blobFromImages(letterboxStack, 1.0, cv::Size(inputW, inputH),
                                   cv::Scalar(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), false, false);
```

hint: I used `Yolo::decodeDetections` in `trt_utils.cpp` and `yolov3.cpp`. Is there any possible alternative for this issue?

Thanks in advance.